# Pagination: Google is indexing pages that do not exist by adding pagination parameters

Tags: seo, pagination, technical-seo

As can be seen from below, Google is adding random parameters to pages and trying to index them. how do we fix this? How can fix this from a technical SEO standpoint

[image]

Comment: What is the screenshot from?

Comment: I doubt that Google is inventing these parameters.  This usually happens because your site actually has links to those URLs. Have your run an SEO crawler against your own site to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it is from Search console

Comment: The other thing you could do would be inspect that URL in Google Search Console.  Google might tell you where it found that URL.

Comment: thanks @StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely encountering 2 separate issues:

1. URLs with *page* parameter are being indexed. Assuming that the *page* parameter does not modify content on the page, this can result in **duplicate content issues**. You can solve this by submitting a Removal Request via Google Search Console and [adding a canonical tag](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls) to the relevant page(s).
2. URLs with *page* parameter are being crawled. This can result in **crawl budget inefficiency**. Google has finite resources/time it allocated to crawling and indexing your website. Ideally, you want it to spend this time wisely, crawling only your most useful/important URLs. **After you've successfully removed the URLs with the *page* parameter from the Index**, you can add a rule in your robots.txt file to [prevent pages with that parameter from being crawled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters) in the future.